# Farady's law electromagnetic induction

Tags: electromagnetism

What does the minus sign in the formula of Faraday’s law of electromagnetic induction denotes?
Is it ok not to use the minus sign?

Comment: If you ignore the minus sign your calculation will yield an induced current in the direction reverse to what it should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The minus sign tells you the *sense* (loosely speaking, the direction) of the emf – provided you know the sign convention!

It works like this… Choose a direction of going through the space inside a circuit' for example it might be along the axis of a coil, in one end and out the other! Call this the *z* direction. Now imagine that you're driving an ordinary (right hand thread) screw through the circuit, so that its point advances in the *z* direction. Call the way (or *sense*) in which you have to *turn* the screw the *positive sense*.

Lenz's law implies that if the flux through the circuit is increasing in the *z* direction then the emf is in the negative sense around the circuit and so on. So $$\mathscr{E}=-\frac{d (n\Phi)}{dt}$$

Things to note…

This still works if you make the opposite choice for the *z* direction.

Strictly, the equation just quoted contains both Faraday's law (about the magnitude of the emf) and Lenz's law (about its direction).

So there's no need to use a minus sign if you're interested only in the magnitude.

This answer doesn't attempt to explain how Lenz's law arises. It can be derived from the principle of conservation of energy, but that's for another day?